# Django template does not exist include or extends tags

Tags: django, templates, tags, include, extends

I am creating a Django project. My question is simple I believe but I am having a tough time trying to figure it out. I have an `index.html` in which I want to render certain things. I decided that I don't want to have a html header for every one of my html pages which to me is insane. I created a `base.html` file to contain a html header and I want to reuse this for my other html files but how do I do this exactly, that is if it's possible.

So what I am mostly not sure about is which tag to use `{% include "base.html" %}` or `{% extends "base.html"%}`. Intuition is telling me I should use `{% include "base.html" %}` because I don't believe I should be inheriting. And then my second question which relates close to this is how do I even `include` or `extends`. I just created a `base.html` file and an `index.html` file and have a `index view` in my `views` file which renders the `index.html` with `context`.

Everything works fine if I were to just use the `index.html` file but when I do `{% include "base.html" %}` in my `index.html` file it does not work and error says temlate `base.html` does not exist. Same goes if I were to use `extends` rather than `include`

Comment: To solve the second issue you need to post the html directories and files location

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't want to have a html header for every one of my html pages

Define a block which you can define in other html pages as you need, like this:

In `base.html`:

```
    {% block header %}{% endblock %}
```

In `index.html`:

```
    {% block header %}
    {% include "header.html" %}
   {% endblock %}
```

In `page_without_header.html`:

```
    // avoid defining the header block
```

Comment: Thanks, so actually I'm new to Django and a lot of basic concepts escape me. In my settings file I fixed the `DIRS` in `templates` to point correctly and restructured my layout in my templates folder. My setup is just a bit different from yours but it works. I tried yours and works too. Thanks